# Finding Equity Of A Home Bought Using A Mortgage.

Tags: finance

Let's say I buy a house using a mortgage where the following information is true:

- The house's original price was $100,000.
- A down payment of 20% was required.
- I get a 30 year mortgage with a 4.5% interest rate.
- The house's value appreciates 3% per year.
- The house has the following expenses that increase 3% per year:

  - Property Tax: $1,500.
  - Total Insurance: $800.
  - HOA Fee: $0.
  - Maintenance: $1000.
  - Other Costs: $200.

What will my equity be after 2 years?

Comment: Hi Seth, maybe folks over [Quantitative Finance SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) would help you with this question

Comment: Thank you! I'll ask them as well.